Plotly choropleth map
I'm trying to make a choropleth map of country Indonesia to visualize the population value of each provinces. I'm using the plotly graph_objects module. The legend is showing, but the map just show as  blank white. How can I solve this problem?
This is my code:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Load data
df_reshaped = pd.read_csv('D:/Projects/population-dashboard-master/data/id-population-2014-2022-reshaped.csv')

# Sidebar
with st.sidebar:
st.title('Indonesia Population Dashboard')
selected_year = st.selectbox('Select a year', year_list)
df_selected_year = df_reshaped[df_reshaped.year == selected_year]
color_theme_list = ['blues', 'cividis', 'greens', 'inferno', 'magma', 'plasma', 'reds', 'rainbow', 'turbo', 'viridis']
selected_color_theme = st.selectbox('Select a color theme', color_theme_list)

# Choropleth map

def make_choropleth(input_df, input_id, input_column, input_color_theme):
    # Get Indonesia geojson data
    geojson = requests.get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/superpikar/indonesia-geojson/master/indonesia-province-simple.json"
    ).json()

    # Plot choropleth map

    choropleth_map = go.Figure(
        data=go.Choropleth(
            geojson=geojson,
            locations=input_df[input_id],  # Spatial coordinates
            featureidkey="properties.Propinsi",
            z=input_df[input_column],  # Data to be color-coded
            colorscale=input_color_theme,
            colorbar_title=input_id,
        )
    )
    choropleth_map.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

    return choropleth_map

# Calling the function
choropleth = make_choropleth(df_selected_year, 'province', 'population', selected_color_theme)
st.plotly_chart(choropleth, use_container_width=True)


and here is the code reference that I use:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# indonesia geojson
geojson = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/superpikar/indonesia-geojson/master/indonesia-province-simple.json"
).json()

# dataframe with columns referenced in question
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Column": pd.json_normalize(geojson["features"])["properties.Propinsi"]}
).assign(Columnnext=lambda d: d["Column"].str.len())

fig8 = go.Figure(
    data=go.Choropleth(
        geojson=geojson,
        locations=df["Column"],  # Spatial coordinates
        featureidkey="properties.Propinsi",
        z=df["Columnnext"],  # Data to be color-coded
        colorscale="Reds",
        colorbar_title="Column",
    )
)
fig8.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig8


The population data used in the map is not in your question, so I got the data from here and converted 3 years to long format and applied your code. Normal switching of years and color maps is working correctly.

The output is this.

@r-beginners may I see your code? It still doesn't work on my end.

@r-beginners Hi. I found the issue already, thank you very much!
